Reqnroll Allure report generation problems
I have a test solution, built on:

.NET Framework 4.7.2
NUnit 3.13
Reqnroll 2.0.0
Allure.Reqnroll 2.12.1
AllureReport.Generator 0.1.0

My solution builds, discovers and executes the tests as expected.
However, I have run into some issues when trying to generate the Allure report (i.e. when attempting to generate HTML output report from JSON format test results and container files).
For regular scenarios, and those with in-step parameter tables, the AllureReport.Generator outputs the report as expected.
But, for test scenario outlines using examples tables (parameterized tests pattern), although the tests execute and output a JSON result and container file for each interative execution, the ReportGenerator fails to create any corresponding content in the report.
According to Allure documentation, each row in the examples table should execute as a separate scenario. The documentation also states

"Allure Reqnroll automatically recognizes this pattern. No additional
configuration is required."

https://allurereport.org/docs/reqnroll-reference/#scenario-outlines
I'm under some pressure to resolve this issue and provide human-readable reports for my test outputs. I'd appreciate any insights or guidance that might help.
Thanks for looking.
*** UPDATE ***
I'm still struggling with this issue: i.e. Allure report for Reqnroll test run fails to pick up test result output from parameterized pattern tests with Examples tables.
I did stumble on this stackoverflow post from 2019, indicating a problem with test scenarios with the same name but in different features failing to report to Allure: Why is only a few results are shown in allure report
This may be related to the issue I'm experiencing: I note that when I look into the results.json files for the parameterized test executions, scenario name for each iteration is indeed the same.
Could this be the problem (contrary to the Allure documentation's assurances that the parameterized tests pattern from Reqnroll was automatically recognised by Allure)??
If this is indeed the problem, is there any way to workaround it?
*** UPDATE ***
My stack has now been updated like so:

.NET 8.0
NUnit 3.14
Reqnroll 2.0.3
Allure.Reqnroll 2.12.1
AllureReport.Generator 0.1.0

Problems persist i.e. Allure fails to report on execution of any parameterized Reqnroll test (non-parameterized tests report as expected).
Question: in spite of the claims in Allure documentation (above), has Allure ever actually worked to produce reports for tests of this type?
Has anyone ever successfully implemented Allure reporting for Reqnroll tests?
Is it possible? Or should I abandon it and search for a more reliable and useful test reporting framework?
Urgent insights and advice needed here.
Thanks.

AllureReport.Generator 0.1.0 isn't an official integration. It's not been maintained since 2018, so please don't use it. According to the package explorer, it has bundled Allure Commandline version 2.7.0 (released in 2018).
Please try to use one of the official Allure distributions: https://allurereport.org/docs/install/

So, bottom line here: without the AllureReport.Generator 0.1.0, is this integration actually possible? Can parameterized Reqnroll tests actually be reported by Allure? Or is Allure incompatible with parameterized pattern in Reqnroll?

According to the documentation https://allurereport.org/docs/reqnroll/#describe-parametrized-tests, it's supported.

Please verify it using the latest version of Allure Commandline (2.32.0 as of today), and feel free to report any issues in the official repository https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/

Sadly, I'm in a company environment and am restricted in how and where I can source packages.
Is there no current allure.bat version packaged for NuGet?
Is there any other way to generate a report from the Allure output result files?

Allure has no official NuGet distribution. Will NPM work for you? https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline

For anyone else who may be considering the use of Allure reports for .NET solutions, be aware that, if you are restricted to NuGet package repositories (as I am), Allure is essentially useless from a practical perspective.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Managed to source the up to date Allure Commandline utility via NPM. This worked to produce the reports as expected (iterative parameterised pattern executions recognised and correctly reported).
One out standing question here: why has the NuGet packaged distribution been abandoned? Is there any plan to reintroduce NuGet packaged availability of this utility for easy integration into .NET projects?
Thanks for guidance and advice on this.

(Note: link to chat in previous response is broken).

I guess it's because there were no such requests from the community. Even for the package you used, there are only 4 downloads daily. For comparison, Java distribution downloaded over 6M times per month, NPM distribution — over 3M per month

Usually, Allure Report is integrated with the CI system https://allurereport.org/docs/integrations/. For local use it generally easier to just install it globally to the system via Brew, Scoop or NPM
